git reset on intermediate commit: is the last commit really lost?
I have a branch2 branching from another branch1 with no additional commits on branch1
so the branch tree is actually linear.
Now I found out that the last commit in branch1 should be actually the first commit of branch2.
So I think it would be save to command git reset --hard HEAD~.
In the documentation, we find, that the commits after are lost,
but I think because we have branch2, this is not true in the given scenario.
If more than one commit, I could command git reset --hard hash
with the hash of the required commit, right?
To be sure, I would like to get the opinion of the community.

Research on the Git reflog -- the commits are likely all still there

"Now I found out that the last commit in branch1 should be actually the first commit of branch2" is a bit strange. The first commit of each branch (except in a few specific scenarios) is the repo's root commit. A branch is not a group of commits, it's just a shortcut to one commit. And that commit has its own ancestry.

@RomainValeri Yes the formulation is strange. I mean from pointer branch1 to pointer branch2 there is a linear history. What I mean is, the commit of branch1 shall be actually one after branch1.

gitk --reflog for the win!

You are right, nothing is lost. To understand why, it's worth knowing a bit about how git works:

In git, a "branch" is actually just a named pointer to a single commit.
Each commit has a pointer to its "parent" (or, for a merge, more than one) pointing.
When we talk about commits being "on a branch", it's technically more accurate to say they are "reachable from a reference"; e.g. "commit abc123 is on branch1" actually means "if you start at the commit referenced by branch1, and follow "parent" pointers backwards, you will at some point reach commit abc123".

What git reset --hard does (as well as discarding uncommitted changes, which is permanent) is change the named reference to point to a different commit.
The warning is that this might leave the previous commit "unreachable" - that is, not in the history of any named branch or tag. Periodically, unreachable commits are "garbage collected", and deleted from the database. Until then, they can still be accessed if you know their hash, or find it somewhere like git reflog
In your case, all the commits reachable from branch1 are also reachable from branch2, so nothing will become unreachable.
You are changing a history like this:
a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f
          ^              ^
       branch1        branch2

To one like this:
a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f
     ^                   ^
   branch1            branch2


Question: If it were more than one commit, say 10 commits or 2 in your example so I need to point branch1 to a instead of c, I could reset to hash a right?

@user2609605 Yep, you can re-point the branch to any commit you can identify (by knowing its hash, referencing another branch name, or using various special syntaxes.

It can also be done another way if you are not working on branch1: git branch -f branch1 b.
